# Calculate the height of a cylinder of maximum volume that can be cut from a cone of height 20 cm and base radius 80 cm

Tags: calculus

I've been staring at this one for 3 hours now and still don't know how to create a single variable from the given information, I tried drawing a diagram but still don't understand it...

I know the procedure behind finding the maximum but just need help with starting off.

If someone can give me hint I'd be grateful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I suppose that a central section of your solid is as in the figure, so you have:$HA=r$,$VH=h$. Put $x=KB$ and, from similar triangle find: $VK=\dfrac{hx}{r}$ and $HK=h(1-\dfrac{x}{r})$.

Now you can find the volume of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

Let the cylinder have radius $r$ and height $h$.  If you imagine slicing the cone and cylinder with a vertical plane through the tip of the cone, you get a triangle from the cone whose dimensions you know.  The cylinder gives you a rectangle that sits on the bottom of the triangle and the upper two corners touch the slant sides of the triangle.  This gives you a relationship between $r$ and $h$.

Answer (score 0):

Does this image help? It isn't to scale, but it should make things a little more clear.
[image]